# Can I delete old negative reviews that no longer apply to my app?

Tags: app-store

One of my apps is seven years old and I recently revamped it. Is there a way to reset my reviews? I have negative reviews that are five to seven years old and no longer apply.

Thanks,

Eli

Comment: Why this is closed?;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete ratings & reviews as a developer on the App Store. The new "reset ratings" option in iTunes Connect, simply allows you to retain the average rating of your app or lets you to reset it.

What you can do is, respond even to the 5-7 years old reviews and answer them.